# Haskell recursive problem, tiny parser. A few things

Tags: haskell, parsing

```
data Expr =  Var Char | Tall Int | Sum Expr Expr | Mult Expr Expr | Neg Expr | Let Expr Expr Expr
    deriving(Eq, Show)
```

That is the datatype for `Expr`, I have a few questions. I'm suppose to parse expressions like `*(Expr,Expr)` as shown in the datatype definition. However I do have some problems with "creating" a valid `Expr`. I use pattern matching for recognizing the different things Expr can be. Some more code:

```
parseExpr :: String -> (Expr, String)
parseExpr ('*':'(':x:',':y:')':s)   = (Mult (parseExpr [x] parseExpr [y]),s)
```

This is not working, obviously. The return type of `parseExpr` is to return the rest of the expression that is to be parsed an a portion of the parsed code as an `Expr`. The right side of this code is the problem. I can't make a valid `Expr`. The function is suppose to call it self recursively until the problem is solved.

ANOTHER problem is that I don't know how to do the pattern matching against `Var` and `Tall`. How can I check that `Var` is an uppercase character between A-Z and that `Tall` is 0-9 and return it as a valid `Expr`?

Generally I can just look at a few parts of the string to understand what part of `Expr` I'm dealing with.

```
Input like: parseProg "let X be 9 in *(X , 2)" Would spit out: Let (Var 'X') (Tall 9) (Mult (Var 'X') (Tall 2))
```

Comment: Input like: parseProg "let X be 9 in *(X , 2)"
Would spit out: Let (Var 'X') (Tall 9) (Mult (Var 'X') (Tall 2))

Comment: Just a heads up, SO has code tags. I edited your post to include them. And what you just added in your comment should probably be added into your original post via the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parseExpr` function returns a pair, so of course you cannot use its result directly to construct an `Expr`. The way I would write this would be something like

```
parseExpr ('*':'(':s) = (Mult x y, s'')
    where (x,',':s') = parseExpr s
          (y,')':s'') = parseExpr s'
```

The basic idea is that, since `parseExpr` returns the leftover string as the second argument of the pair, you need to save that string in each recursive call you make, and when you've handled all the subexpressions, you need to return whatever is left over. And obviously the error handling here sucks, so you may want to think about that a bit more if this is intended to be a robust parser.

Handling `Var` and `Tall` I would do by just extracting the first character as is and have an `if` to construct an `Expr` of the appropriate type.

And if you want to write more complex parsers in Haskell, you'll want to look at the Parsec library, which lets you write a parser as pretty much the grammar of the language you're parsing.

Comment: I just emailed my professor asking if we are allowed to use Parsec. Thank you for the reply, I'll test it out.